# Gradient imageView iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I am customizing my UITableView and I figured out how to set the selected color of each cell. In my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, I have the following code:

```
    UIView *bgColorView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    [bgColorView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
    [cell setSelectedBackgroundView:bgColorView];
    [bgColorView release];
```

But it is a solid orange. I want to make it more slick looking, and have it be a slight gradient from light orange to darker orange. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd use Core Graphics (a.k.a. Quartz) to draw a gradient in your view's `-drawRect:` method:

```
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGFloat colors[8] = {1.0, 0.75, 0.30, 0.5, 0.7, 0.2, 1.0, 0.8};
CGColorSpaceRef space = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(space, colors, NULL, 2);
CGContextDrawLinearGradient(ctx, gradient, top, bottom, NULL);
```

You can limit the area that the gradient fills by creating a path in the current context (ctx) and the clipping to it using `CGContextClip(ctx);`. `top` and `bottom` are CGPoints that define the beginning and end of the gradient.

Answer (score 3):

You will have to override the view's drawRect method to draw the gradient.  It can be kind of a PIA, but you can also check out this open source component which may work:

http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/gradient-view

Answer (score 1):

@Caleb's answer is right on; I do this for a variety of things.

What no one has mentioned is that the view for which you need to implement `drawRect:` is a custom `UITableViewCell`.

Answer (score 0):

simple google search will find your answer ....

http://bluesplat-tech.blogspot.com/2009/03/gradient-shading-uiview.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want a complex or subtle gradient, you can set a background image that is partial alpha and set the cell background color to change appearance.